# ejabberd opening s2s connection to proxy.eu.jabber.org

Tags: elixir, ejabberd, phoenix-framework

I have a local setup of ejabberd on a Phoenix application. For testing it, I created an account and logged in using Pidgin. But I noticed something odd in the logs:

```
iex(8)> [info] (#Port<0.25178>) Accepted connection 127.0.0.1:34684 -> 127.0.0.1:5222
[info] ({socket_state,gen_tcp,#Port<0.25178>,<0.899.0>}) Accepted authentication for ankush by ejabberd_auth_mnesia from 127.0.0.1
[info] ({socket_state,gen_tcp,#Port<0.25178>,<0.899.0>}) Opened session for ankush@localhost/178547105681237390401298
[info] New s2s connection started <0.901.0>
[info] Trying to open s2s connection: localhost -> proxy.eu.jabber.org with TLS=false
[info] s2s connection: localhost -> proxy.eu.jabber.org (remote server not found)
[info] Reconnect delay expired: Will now retry to connect to proxy.eu.jabber.org when needed.
```

Why is an `s2s` connection being opened? I think because I'm on localhost and trying to connect using a client, the connection type should be `c2s`? Finally, where does the `proxy.eu.jabber.org` bit come from?

What I'm trying to do is run a fully functional local server on which I can have two users logged in and chatting. What's going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, so I figured out that this was because of Pidgin. One of its settings was to use `proxy.eu.jabber.org` as a file service, and I guess that's why it was opening an `s2s` connection. When I changed the setting to `no proxy` these messages disappeared.